# Using a Console Cable, Error "Could not find PTY", MAC

Tags: serial, laptop, serial-console

I'm trying to follow AdaFriuts tutorial on using a Pi over a serial cable on my Mac, link bellow, and I'm stuck with an error that reads "Could not find PTY" despite having all the right GPIO connections. Has anyone else experienced this error if you've tried the same?

Note I used the second driver "If using Lion or Mountain Line or later OS X, try this driver here http://changux.co/osx-installer-to-pl2303-serial-usb-on-osx-lio"

I also didn't use the USB B power supply, as I was afraid of giving my Pi to much power, and it seemed to be getting enough power from my computer.

Tutorial here:
http://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-5-using-a-console-cable/overview

Answer (score 2):

Seems like whatever distribution you're running on Raspberry doesn't have `getty` or some equivalent attached to the serial port (and the tutorial doesn't as much as mention that necessity).

Check /etc/inittab for a line looking similar to:

```
  T0:23:respawn:/sbin/getty -L ttyAMA0 115200 vt100
```

Make sure there's no `#` in front of it. If there is, remove it. If the line is missing, add it, then reboot the Pi.

Also note the quote

> The device will have a slightly different name to mine. So, type the line above as far as "cu.PL" then press the TAB key to auto-complete to whatever your device is called, before adding 115200 (which is the baud rate) to the end.