# Booting up a headless Raspberry Pi using Mac OS X

Tags: raspbian, networking, headless, boot-issues, cable

I bought the Raspberry Pi Model B (Raspberry Pi Ultimate Starter Kit off Amazon) thinking this would be my first and final purchase for a while, but have been unsuccessful in getting the computer running without a keyboard.  I followed the endless tutorials online about a "headless setup" and want to avoid buying more if I don't have to, especially just starting out.

Here is what I did.

1. I downloaded the zip file for [Raspbian](http://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/).
2. I formatted my SD card using tutorial on elinux.org titled "[On Mac OSX--Using system tools mostly graphical interface](http://elinux.org/RPi_Easy_SD_Card_Setup#Run_an_App_.28Only_with_graphical_interface.29)".  There are some nice videos that I watched in tandem ([Keith's Pi Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/user/KeithsPiTutorials)).
3. ATTEMPT 1 - Use the console cable (as suggested by the YouTube video cited above) and written down in the Adafruit tutorial (Lesson 5 on their site).  Unfortunately, I got an error elaborated in this post, [Using a Console Cable, Error "Could not find PTY", MAC](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8798/using-a-console-cable-error-could-not-find-pty-mac).

Question for Attempt 1: Where is the `/etc/inittab` file elaborated in the post above and numerous online forums?  Does this directory exist even if I haven't booted up and configured my Raspberry Pi?  If it does exist, how do I access it?

3. ATTEMPT 2 -  I tried plugging in my Raspberry Pi to a router, but did not find its IP address.  On the terminal, I used:

   arp -a

I got a list of IP addresses as shown in the picture of my [terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSDnp.png).

[image: My Terminal]

I then tried to SSH into the Pi using the command:

```
ssh pi@IPADDRESS
```

and each time got `connection refused`.  Then I accessed my router by navigating to `http://192.168.0.1/`.  However, still no new IP addresses was listed there.  I then tried downloading the application "Pi Finder".  But again, no luck.  I then thought maybe the Wi-Fi USB accessory included in the kit might improve my chances.  But it did not.

Question for Attempt 2: Where is the IP Address for my Pi?  Again, am I experiencing difficulties since I haven't configured my Pi yet?  Why is the IP address not showing up?

Comment: Does the Pi actually boot?  You should see the green LED flickering and eventually after about 20 seconds the network LEDs should be lit (if you have an ethernet cable plugged in).  /etc/inittab is on the ext4 (second) partition of the SD card.

Comment: The Pi does boot.  I see green LED flickering and then more lights turn on after I plug in the ethernet cable.

Comment: How do I access the second partition?  I have tried using the terminal and all I get is "boot".  Specifically, `\Volumes\boot`

Comment: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/13437/how-to-mount-a-raspbian-sd-card-on-a-mac

Comment: `arp` will only show the address after it is connected to the Mac Check the lights as on http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Normal_LED_status You need to find the Pi's address - the easiest way is from your router.

Comment: on the Mac `nmap -sP 192.168.0.*` may help

Comment: @Milliways - nmap isn't installed on my Mac (OS X 10.9.3).   Any suggestion on where to find it?

Comment: I haven't gotten to try Millway's suggestion yet.  Will do this when I get back to the pi tonight.  I have Homebrew on my computer and I just used `brew install nmap`.  Otherwise, there is a .dmg file to do it: http://nmap.org/download.html#macosx

Comment: Download from http://nmap.org/

Comment: ACT light comes on strong when I first plug the Pi in (5 seconds at least), but turns off soon after.  The PWR light then stays nice and bright as long as it is plugged in.  If I do not plug in the ethernet cable, there is no other light.  I put in the USB wifi adapter, and no other light goes on.  I do not see any display on the TV via the HDMI cable.

Comment: ACT light comes on strong when I first plug the Pi in (5 seconds at least), but turns off soon after.  The PWR light then stays nice and bright as long as it is plugged in.  If I do not plug in the ethernet cable, there is no other light.  I put in the USB wifi adapter, and no other light goes on.  I see this screen: http://www.ozone3d.net/public/jegx/201307/raspberrypi_model_b_first%20boot_screen.jpg

Comment: I tried nmap, but still no luck at locating the host.  Can I be certain that wifi adaptor is working?  Is the pi connecting to my local network?  In general, are wifi signals assigned an IP address for all available routers?

Comment: You originally said "I tried plugging in my raspberry pi to a router" - Now you are talking about WiFi! Attempting to use WiFi (and the attendant power problems) are one of the major issues on this site. Get it working with a wired conection.

Comment: Thank you, Milliways and joan.  I have been working on this for the past three days (summer break) and just been futzing endlessly.  I hooked it up via ethernet cable to my friend's modem and it worked flawlessly, finally!  I learned a lot including:

 (1)  wifi is a power sink
 (2)  hook up the raspberry pi to a tv to ensure it is working
 (3)  LED lights are an excellent way to determine the current state of the pi.
 (4)  nmap command is more useful to find IP's on a router than arp, as the latter only shows connected to my Mac.

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote a blog post on how I managed to do it: 
[Install Raspberry Pi headless on OS X](https://retosteffen.ch/2016/03/install-raspberry-pi-headless-os-x/).
But your problem sounds to me like the system hasn't installed and or booted up correctly. For copying Raspbian on the SD card I used [Pi Filler](http://ivanx.com/raspberrypi/) that formatted the card and copied the Raspbian img file onto the card.

I also had problems getting the right IP address as my DHCP was being contrary but Pi Finder did a good job of finding it.

Comment: It's great that you wrote a blog on this. However, whilst your link may answer the question, it would be preferable to include the essential parts of the linked here, and provide the link for citation. As such, this is a link only answer, and links tend to die over time, which will drastically reduce the usefulness of your answer. Please see the stack exchange policy on link only answers: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer. If you could edit your answer to include the relevant information, then that would be great.

Comment: Just a brief comment here from my end. Unzipping the latest iso images of raspbian when using a mac works well with The Unarchiver app ( http://wakaba.c3.cx/s/apps/unarchiver.html ) and then following the standard instructions with `dd ...` ( https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/mac.md ). I am just mentioning this, because the default unzip utility that os x has does not work well for the decompression of the iso image and then even if the raspberry has lights blinking and appears to be booting, it is not really booting.

Answer (score 1):

I've used an Ethernet cable connected directly to my PC. 
Just follow these steps:

1. Burn/copy your std RPi img to SD card
2. Connect your RPi to your PC using a ethernet cable.
3. Start your RPi.
4. When started, open a Terminal in your PC and issue: `$ ssh pi@raspberrypi.local`  (password: raspberry). If `raspberrypi.local` doesn't work, try `raspberrypi`.
5. Done.